# Do you know how to put space in the PL/SQL for output?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
set serveroutput on;

declare
 CURSOR c1 IS
 SELECT name, street, city
 FROM sporting_clubs
 WHERE state = 'MO';
  v_name c1%rowtype;

begin
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NAME' || '||'  ||'STREET'|| '||' ||  'CITY'     );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------');
 OPEN c1;
 LOOP
 FETCH c1 INTO v_name;
 EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE
(v_name.name || ' | | ' || v_name.street ||   ' | | '   ||v_name.city);

 END LOOP;
 CLOSE c1;

END;
```

The code is fine, but I want to put space as like the picture shown below. Left picture is my output.

[image]

Comment: use the space bar key ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: What is your front-end application? SQL\*Plus will trim leading spaces, but not spaces within the string. This is the DEFAULT behavior. If you SET SERVER OUTPUT ON FORMAT WRAPPED (or FORMAT TRUNCATED) you will change this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NAME' || char(9)|| '||' ||'STREET'|| char(9) || '||' || 'CITY' );
```

here 9 passed in char function is ascii of tab.

your space should be within quotes in order to see it in effect on your output.

also fire this command before executing ur pl/sql block:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON FORMAT WRAPPED
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is still same.

Comment: It may problem on the runner.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I am missing something, but your code uses

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NAME' || '||'  ||'STREET'|| '||' ||  'CITY'    );
```

which is a convoluted way of writing

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NAME||STREET||CITY');
```

Now if you want this:

```
       NAME       ||      STREET          ||    CITY
```

then just put that in the message:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('       NAME       ||      STREET          ||    CITY' );
```

(You may need to `set serverout on format trunc` to prevent word-wrapping, as otherwise SQL*Plus trims whitespace.)

For example (sorry, couldn't resist a tidy-up):

```
set serverout on format trunc

begin
    dbms_output.put_line('       NAME       ||      STREET          ||    CITY' );
    dbms_output.put_line('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------');
    dbms_output.put_line('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------');

    for r in (
        select c.name, c.street, c.city
        from   sporting_clubs c
        where  c.state = 'MO'
    )
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(r.name || ' | | ' || r.street || ' | | ' || r.city);
    end loop;
end;
/
```